# PHP 4 won't take PHP.ini changes after Apache restart

Tags: php, php4

We have a very old PHP application that needs PHP 4 to run.  We're decommissioning the old server and so I've built PHP 4 on the new server (Ubuntu 13.04 32 bit).  When I did `./configure` I made sure to do `--with-config-file-path=/etc/php4/php.ini`.  I'm trying to enable error logging, but my changes to the `php.ini` don't seem to be taking hold.

Yes, the file exists and is owned by the Apache user

```
nick@server:/etc/php4$ ls
php.ini
```

Yes, I restarted Apache.  And yes, it shows up in the `phpinfo()`:

```
Configuration File (php.ini) Path   /etc/php4/php.ini
```

Does the `--with-config-file-path` only take hold at compilation time and thus in order to make changes I have to recompile?  Or does it work the same as newer versions of PHP?

For example, in the `php.ini` I've turned off `display_errors`, but `phpinfo()` shows:

```
display_errors  On
```

Note that it shows `On` for both the local and master values for this server.

Also, I'm sorry for perpetuating PHP 4

My [php.ini](http://pastebin.com/VSpy4BC9) and [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vXCSA.png) of phpinfo to prove I'm not lying

Comment: Man, I was ready to hit the edit button and fix your "4" typo.

Comment: create a page with phpinfo(); on it... this should tell you the ini php is using for the webserver. Make sure your editing the right one

Comment: I already did that...?  The path is in the question as well as me doing an `ls` to show you that it exists and that I've been editing the correct one.

Comment: Did you make sure `display_errors` is not overridden locally using `.htaccess`?

Comment: My guess is that the php.ini file is owned by `root` and you webserver doesn't have access to it therefore is just using the default configuration.

Comment: Are you sure PHP ini values aren't modified elsewhere down the line? It may happen in a .htaccess or in PHP code via `ini_set`. Create a test PHP file with only `ini_set("diaplay_errors", 0); ehco phpinfo(); ini_set("display_errors", 1); echo phpinfo()` and compare...

Comment: The `php.ini` has global read, so that isn't the problem (I can change the owner if you guys think that will help).  The `phpinfo()` shows both local and global settings and for `display_errors` it shows `On` for both, so it's not being overriden locally and it's not being taken up from the `php.ini`.

Comment: @tubaguy50035 Maybe something is cached?

Comment: I'd suggest pasting your whole php.ini and php_info() output into two pastebins

Comment: apache module or fastcgi module? Because if the latter, you might need to restart fastcgi instead...

Comment: Apache module.  I wish it were easy :)

Comment: I don't know the answer to the question, but I just wanted to say I'm impressed you've managed to get php4 even to compile and run on an up-to-date OS. You might want to add the OS information to the question; not sure if it's relevant, but it could be.

Comment: Try changing  the value of `display_startup_errors` to `On` in your `php.ini` and see if it makes a difference. If it doesn't, it's not loading that php.ini file it's saying it is.

Comment: Yeah, that didn't do anything either.  I figured it wasn't loading it, thus my question :)

Comment: @PLB I doubted, but rebooted the whole server just in case.  Same issues after reboot.

Comment: I'm assuming nothing in the log files?

Comment: Nope.  Apache logs are all I have and it since the errors I'm seeing aren't fatal, it just shows 200's.  Me seeing the errors in the Apache logs wouldn't help me though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`--with-config-file-path` expects a directory, not a filename. So with your confiuration PHP would look for `/etc/php4/php.ini/php.ini`.

Background:
The reason for taking a path is that in fact PHP is looking for different files in order: First a SAPI specific file `php-$SAPI.ini` and then the generic `php.ini`. This allows i.e. using a different configuration on CLI where initial startup time matters more and other caching settings (apc etc.) are required.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense.  Recompiling now!